# First n letters equal for the name property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongo collection `person` with name values like this:

```
aaaaaa
aaaabb
aaabbb
aabbcc
aabccc
aacccc
```

I want to find all names with same first three letters. So the result should be like this:

```
count: 3, [aaaaaa, aaaabb, aaabbb]
count: 2, [aabbcc, aabccc]
count: 1, [aacccc]
```

I know it's some sort of aggregation, but I didn't find exact match query myself.

Is there such a query?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: Yes regex would be my first choice if I already know the string that I've tired to find. I want count/aggregate all of documents in the database that have first n letters the same (in my case 3). But, maybe my regex is rusty, please help :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$substr` operator in the `$project` stage to get the first n characters(n-prefix) of the name. `$substr` is used to get the sub strings from a string. Then, have a `$group` stage to group by the prefix and use `$sum` operator to count the names in the group and a `$push` operator to add the names to a list. Optionally, have a `$sort` stage, to sort by the count.

Your pipeline would look like:

```
db.person.aggregate([
    {"$project":
        {"name":1, 
        "3name":{"$substr":["$name", 0, 3]}
        }
    }, 
    {"$group": 
        {"_id":"$3name", 
        nameList:{"$push" : "$name"}, 
        "count":{"$sum":1}
        }
    }, 
    {"$sort" : {"count":-1}}
])
```

Sample Output:

```
{ "_id" : "aaa", "nameList" : [ "aaaaaa", "aaaabb", "aaabbb" ], "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "aab", "nameList" : [ "aabbcc", "aabccc" ], "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "aac", "nameList" : [ "aacccc" ], "count" : 1 }
```

Or you can have the $substr in the $group stage directly.

```
db.person.aggregate([        
    {"$group": 
        {"_id":{"$substr":["$name", 0, 3]}, 
        nameList:{"$push" : "$name"}, 
        "count":{"$sum":1}
        }
    }, 
    {"$sort" : {"count":-1}}
])
```

Comment: That's the way.

Comment: Move  `{"$substr": [ "$name", 0, 3] }` into the `$group` stage and remove the `$project` stage and you have my vote:)

Comment: @Styvane: Thanks for the improvement suggestion. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a single query can achieve it however as you said aggregation has a scope. I am not going to write the exact aggregation but can suggest an idea of pipeline which in my opinion can achieve it.

Well first you need to use $project in the pipeline create a new valiable say prefix and the value should be first three letter of person name some thing like  `prefix: { $substr: [ "$name", 0, 3 ] }`

secondly in the pipeline you can call $group on the created prefix variable and $sum : 1 to get the count.

This will provide you a list of document with each prefix the count of name.

You can enhance to get more data or data ina  different way.